# ODesk rejects for IP irregularities. Is that fair?

Tags: freelance-websites

Just recently I had an incident with ODesk where they rejected and permanently banned me from freelancing. This blog post will highlight the support interactions I had with them in great detail:

http://rantscrimination.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/odesk-rejects-me-from-freelancing-just.html

This thread just shows that they limited my financial transactions. However in a more recent thread (a new support case) they told me that I was permanently banned because of IP location irregularities. I will upload another blog post with those details. I am not sure how the irregularities came from but IP addresses cannot be solely used to ban a user from freelancing. They even told me not to contact them in the future. Do you guys think this is justified? How can I possibly recover my account? I even provided legitimate documents to prove my identity. Frankly I think they should have a better way to verify ODesk freelancers.

Comment: Did you put UK or Bangladesh as your location? It suspect this could be the reason.

Comment: This question shouldn't be downvoted. Please give a reason when you downvote. I'm making a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from ODesk TOS:

> You agree that you are not: (a) a citizen or resident of a geographic area in which access or use of the Site is prohibited by applicable law, decree, regulation, treaty, or administrative act; (b) a citizen or resident of, or located in, a geographic area that is subject to U.S. or other sovereign country sanctions or embargoes; or (c) an individual, or an individual employed by or associated with an entity, identified on the U.S. Department of Commerce's Denied Persons or Entity List, the U.S. Department of Treasury's Specially Designated Nationals or Blocked Persons Lists, or the Department of State's Debarred Parties List or otherwise ineligible to receive items subject to U.S. export control laws and regulations or other economic sanction rules of any sovereign nation.

Unfortunately Bangladesh is on a U.S. Embargo list: http://www.sanctionswiki.org/Category:FinCen_Embargoed_Countries

Since ODesk operates in the United States and must comply with U.S. law, they cannot keep you as a freelancer there.

Comment: I am a resident in the UK though.

Comment: are you saying that no one from Bangladesh can work on oDesk? I saw thousands of the workers.

Comment: Thats the thing, I set up my ODesk profile when I was in Bangladesh. Now that I have moved here I didn't get into updating the profile because I didn't use it. Only recently I logged in to see the financial transaction limit and now they just permanently banned me. They gave me the reason after banning me as well, so I didn't have any chance to appeal.

Comment: You live in the UK, but are you a UK citizen?  There is a difference and it is significant.  Clause (a) in the highlighted TOS above would apply to you if you are a citizen of Bangladesh, regardless of where you live.